# Hashing on MacOS using API provided by OS

Tags: c++, macos, hash, cryptography, objective-c++

For our C/C++ app we are using [Security Transforms API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/SecurityTransformsBasics/SecurityTransformsBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801-CH2-SW5) for doing some basic encryption/decryption.
And now we need to calculate hash (especially SHA256) of data, and though documentation claims that Security Transforms also provides a way of hashing, but seems there is no details of how to do it. And seems google doesn't bring any example or details on it as well.
So question is:
Is it really possible to calculate hash (SHA256 if possible) using Security Transforms?
And if no, then is there any other API (provided by Apple) to calculate it using C/C++?

Comment: Downvoter, could you please clarify the reason of downvoting, to make it easier to improve the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate SHA256 hash in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866001/generate-sha256-hash-in-objective-c)

Comment: @jww Thanks for note, but that's slightly different question, as it's about using objective c, but here we need solution on c++, as well as with Security Transforms if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a lot it turned out that it's **possible** with [Security Transforms API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/SecurityTransformsBasics/SecurityTransformsBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801-CH2-SW5) though it was not documented. To make it work, crafted samples of [AES encryption](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/EncryptionandDecryption/EncryptionandDecryption.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801-CH3-SW3) with [SecDigestTransformCreate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1394846-secdigesttransformcreate?language=objc) and used list of available hashing algorithms [there](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecdigestsha2?language=objc).

Here is a C and C++ friendly solution:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <Security/Security.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <vector>
#else // C
#include <stdbool.h> // For adding boolean support
#endif // __cplusplus

// Convenience define for cleanup
#define _CLEANUP_IF(a) if ((a)) goto Cleanup;

#ifdef __cplusplus
// Wrap into class in case of C++

class Sha256Calculator {
public:
#endif // __cplusplus

    // Calculates SHA256 hash from given array of data and returns array
    // Note: Parameter "outHash" is manually allocated so consider calling free(outHash) after using it
    static bool calculateSha256(uint8_t** outHash, size_t* outHashSize, const uint8_t *data, const size_t dataSize)
    {
        bool result = false;
        CFErrorRef error = NULL;

        SecTransformRef digestTransform = NULL;

        CFDataRef sourceData = NULL;
        CFDataRef outDataRef = NULL;
        const UInt8 * outData = NULL;
        CFIndex outDataSize = 0;


        // Create a CFData object from the source
        sourceData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const UInt8*)data, dataSize);
        _CLEANUP_IF(!sourceData);

        digestTransform = SecDigestTransformCreate(kSecDigestSHA2, 256, &error);
        _CLEANUP_IF(error);

        SecTransformSetAttribute(digestTransform, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, (CFDataRef)sourceData, &error);
        _CLEANUP_IF(error);

        outDataRef = (CFDataRef)SecTransformExecute(digestTransform, &error);
        _CLEANUP_IF(error);
        _CLEANUP_IF(!outDataRef);


        // Extract data from CFDataRef to array
        outData = CFDataGetBytePtr(outDataRef);     // Returns read-only (UInt8*) pointer to the data
        outDataSize = CFDataGetLength(outDataRef);


        if (outHash) {
            *outHash = (uint8_t*)malloc(outDataSize);
            if (*outHash) {
                memcpy(*outHash, outData, outDataSize);
                if (outHashSize) {
                    *outHashSize = (size_t)outDataSize;
                }
                result = true;
            }
        }

        // Notes:
        //   * All the objects are released except "outData" since it's handled and cleaned by using outDataRef
        //   * CFRelease throws error if the passed object is NULL, so check objects before releasing

    Cleanup:
        // Use CFShow(error) for getting details about error
        if (error) { CFRelease(error); }
        if (digestTransform) { CFRelease(digestTransform); }
        if (sourceData) { CFRelease(sourceData); }
        if (outDataRef) { CFRelease(outDataRef); }

        return result;
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
    // Convenience method for cpp using vectors
    static bool calculateSha256(std::vector<uint8_t>& outHash, const std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
    {
        // Call original method
        uint8_t * outHashArray = nullptr;
        size_t outHashSize;
        bool result;
        result = calculateSha256(&outHashArray, &outHashSize, data.data(), data.size());
        if (!result)
            return false;

        // Put resulting array in vector
        outHash.clear();
        outHash.insert(outHash.end(), &outHashArray[0], &outHashArray[outHashSize]);

        // Clean allocated array
        if (outHashArray)
            free(outHashArray);

        return result;
    }
};
#endif // __cplusplus
```

**Note:**
In order to use **any other** hashing algorithgm instead of SHA256 feel free to modify the line:
`SecDigestTransformCreate(kSecDigestSHA2, 256, &error);`
with desired available hashing algorithm [name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecdigestsha2?language=objc) and appropriate length.

PS Hope, Apple will guys will update their documentation...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about Security Transforms. You can use Apple's CommonCrypto library for this, though.

Oddly much of CommonCrypto does not seem to be well documented (at least that I can find), but in https://opensource.apple.com//source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-7/CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h.auto.html find the following declarations:

```
extern int CC_SHA256_Init(CC_SHA256_CTX *c);
extern int CC_SHA256_Update(CC_SHA256_CTX *c, const void *data, CC_LONG len);
extern int CC_SHA256_Final(unsigned char *md, CC_SHA256_CTX *c);
```